# Unable to set a custom class for UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am following an intro to Swift guide and have an issue with one of the practical examples. I'm not able to set the custom class for a `UITabBar` via the dropdown on the storyboard.

I have other blank scenes that I can change to the custom class that I want. Just not the `UITabBar`. The other instances where a similar question to this was asked, don't resolve my issue.

For reference I have "ViewController" and "SecondViewController" files which can be referenced in these other scenes. I am using Xcode 11.

Also below is the example I am trying to work from:

[image: Inherit from UIViewController]

[image: Example I am using as reference]

And here is my project:

[image: My Xcode project]

Comment: For changing the class from the default `UITabBarController` to your `CustomTabBarController`, your custom class needs to be inheriting from `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Great you are correct. The guide explicitly stated to have the "SecondViewController" inherit from the UIViewController however when I change to inherit from "UITabBarController" it appears in the dropdown and I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created any SecondViewController class.

Go to File-> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class -> Name of Class and tap create.

Comment: I have created the file and class in my project and am able to use in the non "UITabBar" scenes. However, I want to change the custom class of the "UITabBar"

Comment: You need UITabBarController or UITabBar? Also, what are you trying to achieve through a custom Tab Bar class? why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode > File > New File and then create a SecondViewController subclass of UITabBarController then assign in to TabBar controller in storyboard

[image]

Comment: I have created the file and class in my project and am able to use in the non "UITabBar" scenes. However, I want to change the custom class of the "UITabBar"

Comment: please make sure secondViewController is a subclass of UITabBarController